# How to save data in database by using ASP.NET Identity (Web Form)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

This question is the next chapter of:
[How to add custom table in ASP.NET IDENTITY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941619/how-to-add-custom-table-in-asp-net-identity)

In the first chapter I asked how to create a custom table in ASP.NET Identity.
In this chapter I'm asking how to save data in database. I tried many ways but I wasn't successful.

After the successful login, system should store some data like:

- [AccountLogID] PK
- [IPv4]
- LoginDate
- [UserId] FK (From User.ID)

My codes look like this:

### IdentityModels.cs

```
namespace Web_WebApp.Models
{
    // You can add User data for the user by adding more properties to your User class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {


        public virtual ICollection<AccountLog> AccountLogs { get; set; }


        public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
        }

    }


    public class AccountLog
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid AccountLogID { get; set; }

        public string IPv4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime LoginDate { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>


    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Web_Identity", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }


        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AccountLog> AccountLog { get; set; }



        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }


    }
}
```

### Login.aspx.cs

```
namespace Web_WebApp.Account
{
    public partial class Login : Page
    {

        string GuidToken = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();



        public static string GetExternalIP()
        {
            try
            {
                string externalIP;
                externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
                externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                             .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
                return externalIP;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }


        protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Validate the user password

            //var AccountLogs = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AccountLog>();
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

            // Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
            var user = manager.FindByName(username.Text);

            if (IsValid)
            {


                if (user != null)
                {

                    {
                        // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
                        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
                        var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(username.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: true);

                        if (!user.EmailConfirmed && result == SignInStatus.Success)
                        {


                            Response.Redirect("/Account/Confirmation?UserConfirmationID=" + user.Id);
                        }


                        switch (result)
                        {
                            case SignInStatus.Success:

                                var AccountLog = new AccountLog()
                                {

                                    IPv4 = GetExternalIP(),
                                    LoginDate = DateTime.Now,
                                    UserId = user.Id,

                                };

                                user.AccountLogs.Add(AccountLog);


                                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);

                                break;
                            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                                //Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");

                                FailureText.Text = "This account has been locked, please try again later.";
                                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                                return;

                            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                                Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                                Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                                RememberMe.Checked),
                                                  true);
                                break;
                            case SignInStatus.Failure:
                            default:
                                FailureText.Text = "Invalid password";
                                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                                break;

                        }


                    }


                }
                else
                    FailureText.Text = "Account not found.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these codes my application runs, I can login but it doesn't save anything as I've mentioned in my code. I don't get any error or warning.

I'm sure something like "SaveChanges()" is missing but I don't know where to put that.

I appreciate your efforts in reaching a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the user through the `ApplicationUserManager`, and after adding a new `AccountLog` entry to the collection `user.AccountLogs`, you'll need to save the user back to the database. AFAIK you can get the Entity framework context (`ApplicationDbContext`?) from OWIN the same way as you get other instances.

```
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:

        var AccountLog = new AccountLog()
        {

            IPv4 = GetExternalIP(),
            LoginDate = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = user.Id,
        };

        user.AccountLogs.Add(AccountLog);

        // get the entity framework context.
        var dbContext = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        // save the changes to objects tracked by this context
        dbContext.SaveChanges();


        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);

        break;
case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
 // removed for brevity.
    break;

}
```

*Note: You might have to get the user again straight from the context, but I don't think that it's necessary, depends on whether or not the user is detached or not*.