# Inheriting Claim for custom permissions in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a requirement to create custom user permissions in my .NET app. These permissions will be of the type Admin on Environment 1, View on Environment 2, Admin on Group 2, etc.

I've created an object model to represent these,  but I'm unsure how to integrate this into the Identity. The Claim class only appears to support key/value pairs, which is not neat for this use.

Do you have any suggestions of how I can accomplish what I need within th Identity framework?

Thanks.
ARK

Comment: I think you have to create table and relate them to identity to define permission on roles as per enviornment to read how to add custome table in identity read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941619/how-to-add-custom-table-in-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 0):

This **is** what claims are for, claim keys are their types, claim values represent actual values.

If you then want a custom authorization, you issue multiple custom claims of type lets say `http://yourapp.com/customclaim` with values `view of environment 1` etc.

The actual issue is that when you have views and environments, claims you issue are in fact *pairs* of these. To make it easier for the recipient to interpret claims, you can then format them somehow, for example `view, environment1`. Remember values are strings and can be interpreted in any way the issuer and client agree upon.