# How to change the table structure of asp.net identity package

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net identity for Roles management but for user creation I am using my own table structure to insert the user signup data but for Role assignment i want to use the asp.net identity role manager , everything is working fine but when  i am calling this below method it says UserID is not found because it check the user record from table "AspNetUsers" but in my case i have a separate table for user Registration.
How to change this i mean where are the classes written which make the relationship between the two tables "AspNetUsers" and AspNetUsers

As shown above is the complete picture of my issue

```
 if (selectedRoles != null)
                    {
                        user.Id = userViewModel.User_Id.ToString();
                        var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRoles);
                        if (!result.Succeeded)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                            ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
                            return View();
                        }
                    }
```

I just want to check the Registration table for the id rather than "ASPNETUSERS" table

Comment: Let the Asp.Net Identity do its intended work and register the user itself. Then grab the ID value and add it to your table creating a relationship between AspNetUsers and your table. Of course you need to update the code template to adapt for this. Otherwise you could look at this answer [Extending asp.net mvc 5 identity with custom tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482339/extending-asp-net-mvc-5-identity-with-custom-tables)

Comment: Thanks Steve I am already saving user into another table , and later that i integrate the identity , so i just need to use my own table to make the relationship with aspnetuserroles table

Comment: Not sure if I have been clear. I mean that you should let the Identity framework do its works, Register users in its table, set roles and relationship in its tables and so on. You could just tap into this system grabbing the ID from the AspNetUsers table and add it to the record of your user table. In this way you could leverage all the Identity functionality (not only registration but also things like change passwords, forgot passwords, user authentication and authorization through controller and method attribute while you keep the relationship with the user for your own purposes)